# Cannot authenticate in PROD environment (symfony2)

Tags: symfony, authentication, environment

It works well in `dev`, but in `prod` it authenticates me and redirects back to login:

```
[2015-03-02 15:01:48] request.INFO: Matched route "admin_auth" (parameters: "_controller": "DEV\AdminBundle\Controller\AuthController::loginAction", "_route": "admin_auth") [] []
[2015-03-02 15:01:49] request.INFO: Matched route "admin_login_check" (parameters: "_route": "admin_login_check") [] []
[2015-03-02 15:01:49] security.INFO: User "xxx@gmail.com" has been authenticated successfully [] []
[2015-03-02 15:01:49] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
[2015-03-02 15:01:49] request.INFO: Matched route "admin_index" (parameters: "_controller": "DEV\AdminBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction", "_route": "admin_index") [] []
[2015-03-02 15:01:49] security.INFO: Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point (A Token was not found in the SecurityContext.) [] []
[2015-03-02 15:01:49] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point [] []
[2015-03-02 15:01:49] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
[2015-03-02 15:01:49] request.INFO: Matched route "admin_auth" (parameters: "_controller": "DEV\AdminBundle\Controller\AuthController::loginAction", "_route": "admin_auth") [] []
```

The error is here, I think, and I don't know how to deal with it:

```
[2015-03-02 15:01:49] security.INFO: Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point (A Token was not found in the SecurityContext.) [] []
```

My security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        DEV\MainBundle\Model\User:
            algorithm:        sha1
            iterations:       1
            encode_as_base64: false

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        user_db:
            propel:
                class: DEV\MainBundle\Model\User
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/admin/auth$
            security: false
            anonymous: true

        admin:
            pattern:    ^/(admin|api)
            form_login:
                login_path:  admin_auth
                check_path:  admin_login_check
                default_target_path: admin_index
            provider: user_db
            logout:
                path:   admin_logout
                target: admin_auth
            switch_user: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN] }
```

Comment: May be in production the user does not have the role `ROLE_ADMIN`

Comment: it has. It is the same database and I test both environments in my localhost.
and the user Is authorized, as it can be seen in logs:

`security.INFO: User "xxx@gmail.com" has been authenticated successfully [] []`

but then it redirects to login again

Comment: Have you cleared the cache (especially the prod)? :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this line:
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER]

I am not very experienced with symfony but maybe:

```
ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
```